# Connected rates of change with Area and feta (Further math question)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, circles, area, related-rates

[Question about the rate of change in delta A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ult3.png)

Hi can anyone explain to me how to do section b of this question? This question is about arcs length, area of sectors and connected rates of change.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is "feta" ?

Comment: Click on the blue link of the title it should be the question.

Comment: "feta $\to$ theta" don't write the name of a greek cheese instead of an angle.